# Deserialize Json, Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

Xamarin Forms. Got a Json string, but how can I convert it in a c # object, without using third-party libraries. So require the framework of the championship in which I participate.

```
public MainPage()
{

InitializeComponent();
string url = "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/Joyuse/JsonTest/users";
using (var web = new WebClient())
{
var response = web.DownloadString(url);
var result = ReadToObject(response);
MyList.ItemsSource = result.last_name;
}
}
public static ClassPerson ReadToObject(string json)
{
var deserializedUser = new ClassPerson();
var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(deserializedUser.GetType());
deserializedUser = ser.ReadObject(ms) as ClassPerson;
ms.Close();
return deserializedUser;
}
```

```
[DataContract]
public class ClassPerson
{
[DataMember]
public int id { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public string first_name { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public string second_name { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public string last_name { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public string city { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public int age { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public string url { get; set; }
}
```

```
https://my-json-server.typicode.com/Joyuse/JsonTest/users
```

Comment: Can you please post this in the English Language so that a wide range of users can understand this, and answer you properly.

Comment: If you are trying to avoid the most popular choice of `Json.NET`, then look at:  `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data

Comment: This does not work for me:(

Comment: `This does not work for me` What does not work?

Comment: the object is empty

Comment: Include your code, object model(s) and sample json data in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JSON is an **array** of `ClassPerson`, not a single `ClassPerson`:)

```
ClassPerson[] persons;

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ClassPerson[]));
    persons = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as ClassPerson[];
}
```

[image]